# jquery create new buuton

Tags: javascript, jquery

I used the following codes to create  a "New button" next to the "button". But, when I click the "New button", it cannot create another "New button". Why? I have defined the "click" event of "button" tag

```
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("button").click(function() {
            $("body").append("<button type=button>New button</button>");
        })
    })
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <button type="button">button</button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `event delegation` for binding events automatically on dynamically added elements.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var button = "<button type=button>New button</button>";

    $(document).on('click', "button", function() {
        $("body").append(button);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(document).on('click', "button", function() {
        $("body").append("<button type=button>New button</button>");
    })
```